# Title goes up if added more text

Tags: html, css, line, spacing

I'm wondering why it is happening here. If delete the text:
"Sed ut persp iciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque."

Then the title of the site will go up,please see the image here:

http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/sgazmtxj4f92ywdkqn82.jpg

And here is the code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/12/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    td.threecol{
        width:28%;
        padding-right:20px;
        padding-left:20px;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#444;
        padding-top:20px;
        border-right:1px solid #ccc;
        vertical-align:top;/* add this line */
    }

#content .secondary-heading{
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#333;
    font-style:normal;
    font-family:Georgia;
    text-align:left;
    /*
    margin-bottom:15px;//remove this line
    margin-top:-100px;//remove this line
    */
    /*line-height:1.4;*/
}
```